# Entity Framework Generates different queries on different workstations

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, firebird

We have problem on single Developer Machine and a few clients.
Single Linq Query Generates two different SQL queries. The problem is in fact that second query has “OUTER APPLY” statement which firebird do not supports.
We think that it isn’t Code issue, but environmental issue, but i will paste code.

linq :

```
AIds = (from x in context.RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST
    where (x.ID_RISKOBJECT.HasValue && x.F_CREATEDON >= Freq.StartDate && x.F_CREATEDON <= Freq.EndDate)
    group x by x.ID_RISKOBJECT into gr
    let lastCreated = gr.Max(p => p.F_CREATEDON)
    select new
    {
        ObjId = gr.Key
        ,
        LastStatus = gr.Where(p => p.F_CREATEDON == lastCreated && p.ID_RISKOBJECT == gr.Key).Select(p => p.F_STATUS).FirstOrDefault()
    }).Where(x => x.LastStatus == 0 || x.LastStatus == 1).Select(x => x.ObjId.Value).ToArray();
```

SQL with OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT 
"G"."ID_RISKOBJECT" AS "ID_RISKOBJECT"
FROM   (SELECT 
    "C"."A1" AS "C1", 
    "C"."K1" AS "ID_RISKOBJECT"
    FROM ( SELECT 
        "E"."ID_RISKOBJECT" AS "K1", 
        MAX("E"."F_CREATEDON") AS "A1"
        FROM "RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST" AS "E"
        WHERE (("E"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NOT NULL) AND ("E"."F_CREATEDON" >=     @p__linq__0)) AND ("E"."F_CREATEDON" <= @p__linq__1)     
        GROUP BY "E"."ID_RISKOBJECT"
    )  AS "C" ) AS "G"
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT FIRST (1) 
    "I"."F_STATUS" AS "F_STATUS"
    FROM "RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST" AS "I"
    WHERE (((("I"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NOT NULL) AND ("I"."F_CREATEDON" >=     @p__linq__0)) AND ("I"."F_CREATEDON" <= @p__linq__1)) AND (("G"."ID_RISKOBJECT" =         "I"."ID_RISKOBJECT") OR (("G"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NULL) AND ("I"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS     NULL)))) AND (("I"."F_CREATEDON" = "G"."C1") AND ("I"."ID_RISKOBJECT" =     "G"."ID_RISKOBJECT")) ) AS "J"    
WHERE (0 = "J"."F_STATUS") OR (1 = "J"."F_STATUS")
```

Working SQL

```
SELECT 
"B"."ID_RISKOBJECT" AS "ID_RISKOBJECT"
 FROM ( SELECT 
        "C"."ID_RISKOBJECT" AS "ID_RISKOBJECT", 
       (SELECT FIRST (1) 
             "I"."F_STATUS" AS "F_STATUS"
              FROM "RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST" AS "I"
         WHERE (((("I"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NOT NULL) AND ("I"."F_CREATEDON" >= @p__linq__0)) AND ("I"."F_CREATEDON" <= @p__linq__1)) AND (("C"."ID_RISKOBJECT" = "I"."ID_RISKOBJECT") OR (("C"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NULL) AND ("I"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NULL)))) AND (("I"."F_CREATEDON" = "C"."C1") AND ("I"."ID_RISKOBJECT" = "C"."ID_RISKOBJECT"))) AS "C1"
   FROM ( SELECT 
         "D"."A1" AS "C1", 
         "D"."K1" AS "ID_RISKOBJECT"
         FROM ( SELECT 
                "F"."ID_RISKOBJECT" AS "K1", 
                MAX("F"."F_CREATEDON") AS "A1"
                FROM "RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST" AS "F"
                WHERE (("F"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NOT NULL) AND ("F"."F_CREATEDON" >= @p__linq__0)) AND ("F"."F_CREATEDON" <= @p__linq__1)
                GROUP BY "F"."ID_RISKOBJECT"
         )  AS "D"
   )  AS "C"    
)  AS "B"
      WHERE (0 = "B"."C1") OR (1 = "B"."C1")
```

Query generated for MSSQL Engine (we supports two db engines in our APP)

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[ID_RISKOBJECT] AS [ID_RISKOBJECT]
FROM   (SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [ID_RISKOBJECT]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID_RISKOBJECT] AS [K1], 
        MAX([Extent1].[F_CREATEDON]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ID_RISKOBJECT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[F_CREATEDON] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[F_CREATEDON] <= @p__linq__1)
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[ID_RISKOBJECT]
    )  AS [GroupBy1] ) AS [Project1]
 OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent2].[F_STATUS] AS [F_STATUS]
    FROM [dbo].[RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[ID_RISKOBJECT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[F_CREATEDON] >=     @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[F_CREATEDON] <= @p__linq__1) AND (([Project1].[ID_RISKOBJECT] = [Extent2].[ID_RISKOBJECT]) OR (([Project1].[ID_RISKOBJECT] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].    [ID_RISKOBJECT] IS NULL))) AND ([Extent2].[F_CREATEDON] = [Project1].[C1]) AND ([Extent2].[ID_RISKOBJECT] = [Project1].[ID_RISKOBJECT]) ) AS [Limit1]    
WHERE [Limit1].[F_STATUS] IN (0,1)
```

Comment: What approach are you using for EF? Code first or database first? I.e. do you inherit from DbContext and DbSet or do you have the .edmx xml files?

Comment: Database First, due legacy issues, we have edmx. i can provide them if they are needed.

Comment: We also supports mssql, i will make some tests, and i will report

Comment: Can it be that one machine has .NET Framework 4 while the other has .NET Framework 4.5 installed?

Comment: no, project is for .net 4

Comment: but maybe it is 4.5 installed on this machine, while others have 4.0, i will check this

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing against SQL Server?

If you are using .edmx then the `ProviderManifestToken` attribute (usually in the first 10 lines of the XML) will indicate the supported set of SQL features. This is determined from the database used when you created or updated the model from the database. E.g. a common issue is working against a SQL 2008 local database then pushing to a 2005 database and finding out that the application crashes because it doesn't support datetime2 in SQL 2005. The fix in this instance is to change the auto-created value from `2008` to `2005`

I am not familiar with working against firebird but suggest looking in this area.

Comment: we had this issue :) like you said, in mssql we fixed it, and currently :  ProviderManifestToken="2008" works fine.

Comment: i will paste whole line from firebird : <Schema Namespace="RiskEntityModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" ProviderManifestToken="2.5" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">

Comment: On MSSQL everything works Fine, problem is specific for firebird :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is between Net Framework 4.5 and firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient.dll - When sb have installed this version of framework - EntityFramework generates outer apply statements for firebird.

Probably Jiri Cincura (cincura.net) should investigate it :)

Problem Solved by downgrading .net framework to 4.0 full