# OUTER APPLY in .net 4.5 and Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

After installing the `.Net 4.5`, there were problems in queries generated by EF. The same query in linq to `.Net 4.0` works correctly. I'm using Firebird database and it does not support command `OUTER APPLY`. Is there any way to modify the following query linq, so that it behaves in a `.Net 4.5`?

Current linq query:

```
int[] AROIds = (from x in context.RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST
               where (x.ID_RISKOBJECT.HasValue && x.F_CREATEDON >= Freq.StartDate 
               && x.F_CREATEDON <= Freq.EndDate)
               group x by x.ID_RISKOBJECT into gr
               let lastCreated = gr.Max(p => p.F_CREATEDON)
               select new
               {
                 ObjId = gr.Key
                 , LastStatus = gr.Where(p => p.F_CREATEDON == lastCreated 
                   && p.ID_RISKOBJECT == gr.Key)
                   .Select(p => p.F_STATUS).FirstOrDefault()
               }).Where(x => x.LastStatus == 0 || x.LastStatus == 1)
               .Select(x => x.ObjId.Value).ToArray();
```

SQL generated for. Net 4.5:

```
SELECT
"Project1"."ID_RISKOBJECT" AS "ID_RISKOBJECT"
FROM (SELECT
    "GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1",
    "GroupBy1"."K1" AS "ID_RISKOBJECT"
    FROM ( SELECT
        "Extent1"."ID_RISKOBJECT" AS "K1",
        MAX("Extent1"."F_CREATEDON") AS "A1"
        FROM "RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST" AS "Extent1"
        WHERE (("Extent1"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NOT NULL)
        AND ("Extent1"."F_CREATEDON" >= 2013-04-17))
        AND ("Extent1"."F_CREATEDON" <= 2013-04-17)
        GROUP BY "Extent1"."ID_RISKOBJECT"
    ) AS "GroupBy1" ) AS "Project1"
OUTER APPLY (SELECT FIRST (1)
    "Extent2"."F_STATUS" AS "F_STATUS"
    FROM "RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST" AS "Extent2"
    WHERE (((("Extent2"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NOT NULL)
    AND ("Extent2"."F_CREATEDON" >= 2013-04-17))
    AND ("Extent2"."F_CREATEDON" <= @2013-04-17))
    AND (("Project1"."ID_RISKOBJECT" = "Extent2"."ID_RISKOBJECT") OR (("Project1"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NULL)
    AND ("Extent2"."ID_RISKOBJECT" IS NULL)))) AND (("Extent2"."F_CREATEDON" = "Project1"."C1")
    AND ("Extent2"."ID_RISKOBJECT" = "Project1"."ID_RISKOBJECT")) ) AS "Limit1"
WHERE (0 = "Limit1"."F_STATUS") OR (1 = "Limit1"."F_STATUS")
```

Comment: *I'm using Firebird database and it does not support command OUTER APPLY* Sounds like a problem with the provider, are you using the right one?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650954/entity-framework-generates-different-queries-on-different-workstations, but I suggest not closing this question, because that other question essentially has "don't install .NET 4.5" marked as an answer...

Comment: I need to install .net 4.5. Can I get EF to work in 4.0 even if it is installed on the environment `.Net 4.5?`

Comment: It's not provider: [Firebird bugtrack](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The only solution, which is what I found while reading in the initial table to the list. Unfortunately, not quite what I meant, but it works.

```
 AIds = (from x in 
        (
           context.RISK_T_ASSESS_HIST.Where(x => x.ID_RISKOBJECT.HasValue && x.F_CREATEDON >= Freq.StartDate && x.F_CREATEDON <= Freq.EndDate)
           .Select(x => new { x.ID_RISKOBJECT, x.F_CREATEDON, x.F_STATUS }).ToList()
        )      
        group x by x.ID_RISKOBJECT into gr
        let lastCreated = gr.Max(p => p.F_CREATEDON)
        select new
        {
           ObjId = gr.Key
           ,
           LastStatus = gr.Where(p => p.F_CREATEDON == lastCreated && p.ID_RISKOBJECT == gr.Key).Select(p => p.F_STATUS).FirstOrDefault()
        }).Where(x => x.LastStatus == 0 || x.LastStatus == 1).Select(x => x.ObjId.Value).ToArray();
```

This issue Entity Framework and will be passed as an error on their forum.