# Downgrade Entity Framework 5 to 4

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

In association with:

[Outer Apply in EF5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083304/outer-apply-in-net-4-5-and-entity-framework)

If you can, then please edit this linq query as to not use `OUTER APPLY`.
The developer stations have `.Net 4.0`, the client computers `.Net 4.5`.
Entity Framework explains in a bad way mark by adding multiple OUTER APPLY not supported by the provider for Firebird. The project has set the target framework to 4.0, but still when starting the client uses 4.5, which query is generated incorrectly. I also tried using Nuget.
Is it possible to make an application to used the `EF 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.5 in an in-place update so there is only one runtime installed on the target machine. It will be either .NET Framework 4 or .NET Framework 4.5. So, even if you target .NET Framework 4 but your machine has .NET Framework 4.5 installed the app will use .NET Framework 4.5 since there is no .NET Framework 4. AFAIK it is not possible to downgrade .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Framework 4 (and VS2012 required .NET Framework 4). 
Targeting is mostly about making sure that you are not using APIs that are not available on the targeted platform and therefore that your application can run there. As for Outer Apply issue - can you file a bug on http://entityframework.codeplex.com for this? Make sure to include the query that started causing Outer Applies in .NET Framework 4.5.